# Edit a portion of YAML file (a multi-line string) with a different mode

Tags: text-editing, multiple-modes

I'm constantly editing a big yaml file with many multi-line strings, which are BASH scripts.

In `org-mode` I would use something like:

```
#+begin_src sh
echo "cool"
#+end_src
```

And then just to `C-c '` (`org-edit-src-code`) to edit this portion of the file in a special "buffer" with the `Shell-script[bash]` mode.

Is it possible to do this in a YAML file? To select a portion of the file and edit it on its own buffer?

An example of this is:

```
something:
  data: |
    # this is my shell script
    echo "cool"
    # the end
```

Is it possible to edit this multi-line string as a `Shell-script[bash]` and *also* having Emacs removing the 4 spaces (which are part of yaml, stucture)? or Can I use `org-edit-src-code` outside `org-mode`?

Comment: Have you looked at _Mutliple Major Modes_ (aka `mmm-mode`)?